# Option to enable/disable connecting to php file or mysql using mobile data?

Tags: centos7

Is there any option to enable/disable connecting to PHP file or MySQL using mobile data? Because this happened with me 2 days ago, and
all users couldn't connect via mobile data all day, but they could using Wi-Fi!

If there isn't any option like that, what could cause this issue?

Comment: There is no such feature. You don't provide enough detail to answer what the underlying cause is, but to ***guess*** :  possibly  a problem with/within the provider network (either your hosting providers, the mobile operators or in between), not your server.

Comment: 2 days ago there were some major routing issues, causing LOTS of connectivity.  https://tech.slashdot.org/story/19/06/24/213234/how-verizon-and-a-bgp-optimizer-knocked-large-parts-of-the-internet-offline-today